# Using FFMPEG to convert Numpy text file to mp3

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I have a text file that contains the output of a Numpy array and would like to use FFMPEG to convert that into an mp3 file.

I've been following [this tutorial](http://zulko.github.io/blog/2013/10/04/read-and-write-audio-files-in-python-using-ffmpeg), and to put it in perspective I have essentially written the `audio_array` that is created to a text file, which I would like to read later on in my program into FFMPEG and convert back into an mp3 file.

I tried modifying the part below as follows, but it doesn't seem to give me an output:

`pipe = sp.Popen([ FFMPEG_BIN,
       '-y', # (optional) means overwrite the output file if it already exists.
       "-f", 's16le', # means 16bit input
       "-acodec", "pcm_s16le", # means raw 16bit input
       '-r', "44100", # the input will have 44100 Hz
       '-ac','2', # the input will have 2 channels (stereo)
       '-i', '[path/to/my/text_file.txt]', 
       '-vn', # means "don't expect any video input"
       '-acodec', "libfdk_aac" # output audio codec
       '-b', "3000k", # output bitrate (=quality). Here, 3000kb/second
       'my_awesome_output_audio_file.mp3'],
        stdin=sp.PIPE,stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)`

Comment: What does the `ffmpeg` console output/log show? Did you first test the `ffmpeg` command manually, unscripted in a command-line interface before trying to script it? I'm not totally clear what your goal is here. Are you trying to use `ffmpeg` for text-to-speech? This can be done with the [flite filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#flite).

Comment: It's not for text-to-speech; what I'm ultimately trying to do is write an mp3 of sounds to a .txt as a Numpy array, where I can modify it later in a program, and then pass that .txt/Numpy-array back to FFMPEG (or some similar utility) and convert it back to an mp3.